# How to run custom function parallel with multi-worker Dask

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cloud, dask

So I just deploy dask on Cloud with scheduler and worker, here the example I deploy with 5 worker (each worker have 1cpu/1thread/1G ram)

```
cluster = DropletCluster(n_workers=5, region="sgp1", image="ubuntu-22-04-x64", size="s-1vcpu-1gb-amd")
client = Client(cluster)
```

And I have some function here

```
def Tester_3():
    found = False
    i = 0    
    start = time.time()
    while not found:
        result_sha256 = sha256_blockchain(i)
        found = bool(re.search(r"^000000", result_sha256))
        if found:
            break
        i+=1
    return f"------Running for {time.time() - start} sekon------"
```

**Try 1**

so when I run this function with client.run, they are sun separately for each worker not run in the same task

```
xx = client.run(Tester_3)
xx
```

here for the result

```
{'tls://143.198.x.x:33785': '------Running for 32.62452673912048 sekon------',
 'tls://159.223.x.x:43919': '------Running for 33.88207650184631 sekon------',
 'tls://159.65.x.x:44949': '------Running for 37.02353572845459 sekon------',
 'tls://159.65.x.x:43181': '------Running for 31.585288524627686 sekon------',
 'tls://206.189.x.x:38597': '------Running for 42.807809591293335 sekon------'}
```

**Try 2**

Then when I try with dask.delayed (also client.submit too), there's only 1 Worker in running

```
z = dask.delayed(Tester_3)()
print(z.compute())

------Running for 37.95407176017761 sekon------
CPU times: user 50.2 ms, sys: 23 ms, total: 73.2 ms
Wall time: 38 s
```

**Try 3**

I already use like multiprocessing (disable daemon on worker) and some PoolExecutor, but they are running in local machine not in the Worker machine

My question is, how should I change the code or flow, so the all worker can run with 1 task (E.g: on Try 2, it can run with all worker). I really appreciate for any kind help

Answer (score 0):

calling `dask.delayed` or `client.submit` will only start the function once, which gets dispatched to one worker, the proper way to start multiple tasks is to use `client.submit` multiple times, and wait for them.

```py
client = Client(cluster)
workers_number = len(client.scheduler_info()['workers'])

# send work to workers
tasks = []
for i in range(workers_number):
    client.submit(Tester_3)

# wait till workers end and get return
for task in tasks:
    print(task.result())
```

this will start as much tasks as the workers you have, but you can dispatch more tasks, and they will be distributed in a round-robin fashion.